# Please help just using html and css how to show hide either of div from nav bar buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `divs`. One displays configure wifi and other displays status. What is happening is that, when I click on the navbar button it shows the Wific configure div and if I click it again it hides it.
and if I click the second button show status div, it shows the status along witht he configure wifi div. then I have to click either of the button for what I do not want to see.

what I want to acheive just using css and html of what I have attempted is to toggle between divs when respective button is clicked in nav bar.

```css
.toggle-content {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-content.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

html {
  font-family: Arial;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 26px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  border-style: groove;
  padding: 10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
}

p,
{
  font-size: 3.0rem;
}

.units {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

</style>
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="toggle active" href="#wifisetup">Configure Wifi</a></li>
  <li><a class="toggle" href="#PotsStatus">Show Status</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="toggle-content" id="wifisetup" style="display:visible; font-size:18px;">
  <h2>Connect to a Wifi Network!</h2>
  <label for="wifi">Choose ssid:</label>
  <select name="wifi" id="ssid">
  </select><br>
  <label for="wifi" id="pass_lbl">Enter password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="pass"></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" value="Rescan">
  <button id="button_save" class="button_wifi" onclick="update()">Connect</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="PotsStatus" class="toggle-content" style="font-size:14px;">
</div>
```

I want to be able to toggle between the two `divs` not toggle on off by clicking the same button in `navbar` twice though even if it exists its ok but when I choose show status the configure wifi div should hide.

Comment: I don't think thats possible only with html and css. You'll probably need to use javascript.

Comment: can you show an example in javascript please? no jquery just using javascript